# How I upload mp3 file in Google drive using C# in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

I have successfully uploaded image file in google drive using C#. But i am facing problem in uploading mp3 file on drive.

How I upload mp3 file in Google drive using C# in MVC?

this my Code for save file:

```
public ServieResponse SaveFileOnGoogleDrive(string url)
       {
           //string url = string.Empty; ; ;
           //string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
           //                 DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};
           string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                          //DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,
                          DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts };
           var clientId = "xxxxxx";      // From https://console.developers.google.com
           var clientSecret = "xxxxxxx";

           // From https://console.developers.google.com
           // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
           var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
           {
               ClientId = clientId,
               ClientSecret = clientSecret
           },
                                                                   scopes,
                                                                   Environment.UserName,
                                                                   CancellationToken.None,
                                                                   new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken")).Result;
           //Once consent is recieved, your token will be stored locally on the AppData directory, so that next time you wont be prompted for consent.

           DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
           {
               HttpClientInitializer = credential,
               ApplicationName = "CTM",
           });

           string filePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filPath"];
           filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath) + url;
           uploadFile(service, filePath, "", "");

           // service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
           //Long Operations like file uploads might timeout. 100 is just precautionary value, can be set to any reasonable value depending on what you use your service for.

           //return Json(new { result = "abc" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
           ServieResponse ob = new ServieResponse();
           ob.ResponseMsg = "Success";
           return ob;
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now my code is working fine. Updated code is:

```
public ServieResponse SaveFileOnGoogleDrive(string url)
   {
       //string url = string.Empty; ; ;
       //string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
       //                 DriveService.Scope.DriveFile};
       string[] scopes = new string[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                      DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                      //DriveService.Scope.DriveAppsReadonly,
                      DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                      DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,
                      DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,
                      DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts };
       var clientId = "65675933715-poet7f7dhjhrmccmalhb41pltho7tusr.apps.googleusercontent.com";      // From https://console.developers.google.com
       var clientSecret = "D8USyz3Pf82wOMi6l2pJehjx";

       // From https://console.developers.google.com
       // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
       var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
       {
           ClientId = clientId,
           ClientSecret = clientSecret
       },
                                                               scopes,
                                                               Environment.UserName,
                                                               CancellationToken.None,
                                                               new FileDataStore("MyAppsToken")).Result;
       //Once consent is recieved, your token will be stored locally on the AppData directory, so that next time you wont be prompted for consent.

       DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
       {
           HttpClientInitializer = credential,
           ApplicationName = "CTM",
       });

       string filePath = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filPath"];
       filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath) + url;
       uploadFile(service, filePath);
       ServieResponse ob = new ServieResponse();
       ob.ResponseMsg = "Success";
       return ob;
   }

public static void uploadFile(DriveService _service, string _uploadFile)
  {
      if (System.IO.File.Exists(_uploadFile))
      {
          var body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
          //File body = new File();
          body.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_uploadFile);
          //body.Description = _descrp;
          body.MimeType = GetMimeType(_uploadFile);
          // body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

          FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
          try
          {
              using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(_uploadFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
              {
                  request = _service.Files.Create(body, stream, body.MimeType);
                  request.Fields = "id";
                  request.Upload();
              }
              var file = request.ResponseBody;
              var fili = file.Id;
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {

          }
      }
      else
      {

      }
  }

private static string GetMimeType(string fileName)
  {
      string mimeType = "application/unknown";
      string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
      Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
      if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
          mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
      return mimeType;
  }
```

Comment: i think ActionViewControl Tags is not correct for this question and i removed it mate